# gsoap and resource management

Tags: c, gsoap

I use gsoap to implement some Web-service in my C program.

I use gsoap like this:

```
int motion_detector_check_status(const char *endpoint, 
        const motion_detector_subscription_result_t *sr, int *status) {
    int rc = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    double _timeout = difftime(sr->termination_time, sr->current_time);
    char timeout[TIMEOUT_MAX_LEN];
    struct soap *soap = soap_new();
    struct _tev__PullMessages request;
    struct _tev__PullMessagesResponse response;
    char *motion_state;

    if (!soap) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    snprintf(timeout, TIMEOUT_MAX_LEN, "PT%.0fS", _timeout < 5.0 ? _timeout : 5.0);

    request.MessageLimit = 1;
    request.Timeout = _timeout < 5.0 ? (int64_t)_timeout : 5.0;
    request.__any = timeout;
    request.__size = sizeof(timeout) + 1;

    rc = soap_call___tev__PullMessages(soap, endpoint, SOAP_ACTION_PULL_MESSAGE,
            &request, &response);

    if (rc != SOAP_OK) {
        soap_print_fault(soap, stderr);
        goto end;
    }

    if (response.wsnt__NotificationMessage && 
            response.wsnt__NotificationMessage->Topic &&
            response.wsnt__NotificationMessage->Topic->__any) {
        if (strstr(response.wsnt__NotificationMessage->Topic->__any, MOTION_ALARM_SRC)) {
            motion_state = strstr(response.wsnt__NotificationMessage->Message.__any,
                    "<tt:SimpleItem Name=\"State\" Value=");

            if (strcasestr(motion_state, "true"))
                *status = 1;
            else
                *status = 0;
        }
    }

    motion_detector_check_status_free_response(&response);
end:
    soap_end(soap);
    soap_destroy(soap);
    soap_free(soap);
    return rc;
}
```

Everything works well, but `struct _tev__PullMessagesResponse` has some pointers to char and other structures.

When I run my program in `valgring` it told me that I have memory leaks and resources referenced through pointers inside `response` aren't free after end of `motion_detector_check_status`. Of course I could write this functions by myself, but I'm wonder does gsoap provides functions to free this resources?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, walking deeper throught docomentation to `soapcpp2` I found option `-Ed` witch generates `soap_del_T` macros for each type used by gsoap.